# How to invoke private endpoint enabled Azure Function App in Azure pipeline?

Tags: azure-functions, azure-pipelines

In my Azure pipeline, through "Invoke Azure Function" task (Agentless Job), I have called a Azure Function App URL which is private endpoint enabled. When I run the pipeline, I am getting the error as "Error 403 - Forbidden".

Also I have tried using Web Hook in project settings and getting the same error.

Please let me know a solution for my issue.

Thanks

Comment: Agree with @Krzysztof, if the issue persists, please add more details regarding the pipeline definition, and error details screenshots.

Comment: Hi wade, I have updated my query description. Please let me know still you need any information.

Comment: Hi @VKD, i add the answer, please have a check, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An **agentless** job is a job that runs **without an agent**. It is used to run tasks that do not require a specific environment or platform.

However you are calling an Azure Function App URL which is **private endpoint** enabled, the call cannot reach to the azure function app as it's blocked.

You can use the **agent job**, which agent has **same private endpoint** with function app, so it's able to access. Otherwise make sure your function app can be accessed in public(private endpoint removed).